# Appendchild() error in php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to add/insert data to an xml doc using php, but I seem to be getting a

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a
>   non-object."

Here is a section of my code and where it's not happy with is:

```
$customer = $customers->item(0)->appendChild($customer);

function insertCustomer()
    {   

        try {
            $xmlFile = "../../data/customer.xml";
            $doc = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
            $doc->formatOutput = true;
            $customer = $doc->createElement('customer');

            $customers = $doc->getElementsByTagName("customers"); 


            $customer = $customers->item(0)->appendChild($customer);
            $newID = getLastId() + 1;
            $id = $doc->createElement('id');
            $idValue = $doc->createTextNode($newID);
            $id->appendChild($idValue);
            $customer->appendChild($id);


            $name1 = $doc->createElement('first_name');
            $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["name"]);
            $value2 = $name1->appendChild($nameValue);
            $name = $customer->appendChild($name1);

            $name = $doc->createElement('surname');
            $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["name"]);
            $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
            $name = $customer->appendChild($name);

            $name = $doc->createElement('password');
            $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["password"]);
            $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
            $name = $customer->appendChild($name);


            $name = $doc->createElement('email');
            $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["email"]);
            $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
            $name = $customer->appendChild($name);

            $name = $doc->createElement('phone');
            $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["phone"]);
            $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
            $name = $customer->appendChild($name);

            $doc->save($xmlFile );
        } catch(Exception $e) { echo $e;} 
        echo "customer successfully registered and your new Id = ". $newID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the xml node with $customers = $doc->getElementsByTagName("customers"); 
 But the return value could be null or empty object with no child items.
 And then  $customers->item(0) would be null reference.
 So  "$customers->item(0)->appendChild($customer); " causes the null reference error.
 Please check the xml content and add the condition command like if.
 Hope this helps you.
Thanks.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <firstname></firstname>
    <lastname></lastname>
    <email></email>
    <phone></phone>
  </Customer>
</Customers>

Comment: Sorry I accidentally clicked on add comment, did you mean if the xml doc is formed?

Comment: I think that the spelling causes the problem.Please fix  "customers" to "Customers"